# can I loop through all pages in Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

How can I loop through all pages in Shopify? I have tried this:

```
{% for page in pages %}

  {{ page.title }} <br>

{% endfor %}
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through up to 50 pages at a time with Liquid pagination:

```html
<ul>
{%- paginate pages by 50 -%}
    {%- for p in pages -%}
        <li>{{ p.title }}</li>
    {%- endfor -%}
    {{ paginate | default_pagination: next: 'Older', previous: 'Newer' }} 
{%- endpaginate -%}
</ul>
```

https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects#pages

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is not possible to iterate over pages in liquid, but we can do it with JS:

```
$.getJSON('/pages.json', function(data) {
    for(p in data.pages ){
         console.log( data.pages[ p ].title );
    }
});
```